# Azure Data Explorer Data Connection DataFormat

Tags: azure-data-explorer

What is the difference between JSON and MULTIJSON data format? Isn't it all a JSON?
When should we use one or the other?
How should the payload look when using one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language#the-json-format

> Azure Data Explorer supports two JSON file formats:
>
> **json:** Line separated JSON. Each line in the input data has exactly one JSON record.
>
> **multijson:** Multi-lined JSON. The parser ignores the line separators and reads a record from the previous position to the end of a valid JSON.

and: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats

> **JSON:** A text file with JSON objects delimited by `\n` or `\r\n`. See [JSON Lines (JSONL)](http://jsonlines.org/).
>
> **MultiJSON:** A text file with a JSON array of property bags (each representing a record), or any number of property bags delimited by whitespace, `\n` or `\r\n`. Each property bag can be spread on multiple lines. This format is preferred over `JSON`, unless the data is non-property bags.

you should choose according to how your source data is formatted. if in doubt, choose `multijson`, as it 'contains' `json`.

example for `json` with 2 records:

```
{"Hello":"World"}
{"Foo":{"Bar":"x"}}
```

example for `multijson` with 2 records:

```
{
   "Hello": "World"
}
{   
    "Foo": {
       "Bar": "x"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know more about this. Why are objects separated by System.newline instead of commas like an usual JSON? { o1, o2 }. Why is there a limitation or if you forgot to mention having a payload like: [ {}, {}, {} ] which is also a valid JSON.

Comment: the payload you included in your comment is covered by the `multijson` format. as i've mentioned in my answer: *"if in doubt, choose `multijson`, as it 'contains' `json`."*