# Azure Data Explorer Stream Ingest formatted JSON Documents

Tags: json, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer, data-ingestion

We ingest JSON messages from Event Hub into Azure Data Explorer via Stream Ingestion.

I created a table with this statement

```
.create table messages(SerialNumber: string, ReceivedUtcTime: datetime, IngestEventEnqueuedUtcTime: datetime, IngestEventProcessedUtcTime: datetime, ProcessEventEnqueuedUtcTime: datetime, MessageVersion: int, MessageType: string, Payload: dynamic)
```

with this Ingestion Mapping:

```
.create-or-alter table messages ingestion json mapping "eventhub_mapping"
'['
  '{"column":"SerialNumber",                "path":"$.serialNumber",          "datatype":"string"     },'
  '{"column":"ReceivedUtcTime",             "path":"$.timestampUtc",          "datatype":"datetime"   },'
  '{"column":"IngestEventEnqueuedUtcTime",  "path":"$.eventEnqueuedUtcTime",  "datatype":"datetime"   },'
  '{"column":"IngestEventProcessedUtcTime", "path":"$.eventProcessedUtcTime", "datatype":"datetime"   },'
  '{"column":"ProcessEventEnqueuedUtcTime", "path":"$.x-opt-enqueued-time",   "datatype":"datetime"   },'  
  '{"column":"MessageVersion",              "path":"$.messageVersion",        "datatype":"int"        },'
  '{"column":"MessageType",                 "path":"$.messageType",           "datatype":"string"     },'
  '{"column":"Payload",                     "path":"$.payload",                 "datatype":"dynamic",   "transform":null    }'
']'
```

The messages we want to ingest look like this:

```
{
  "timestampUtc": "2022-03-07T00:00:00Z",
  "eventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2022-03-07T00:00:00Z",
  "eventProcessedUtcTime": "2022-03-07T00:00:00Z",
  "messageType": "Information",
  "messageVersion": 1,
  "serialNumber": "ser-1",
  "payload": {
    "TimestampUtc": "2022-03-07T00:00:00Z",
    "Value": 123.12
  }
}
```

When i try to ingest those messages i get errors during ingestion and nothing gets stored in the table.

However, i found out, if i transmit the JSON as a single line without formatting, the messages gets stored as expected.

So this message works:

```
{"timestampUtc":"2022-03-07T00:00:00Z","eventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2022-03-07T00:00:00Z","eventProcessedUtcTime":"2022-03-07T00:00:00Z","messageType":"Information","messageVersion":1,"serialNumber":"ser-1","payload":{"TimestampUtc":"2022-03-07T00:00:00Z","Value":123.12}}
```

Is this something to be expected or can i configure this behavior to allow for every valid JSON to be ingested into Data Explorer?

I have read about the option to [ingest multiline json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615951/azure-data-explorer-data-connection-dataformat/65616418#65616418) but this does not seem to be supported when creating the ingestion mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the multiline json in your EventHub connection, or in the ingestion command (not in the mapping).

See the ingestion properties [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-properties) (specifically the "format" property) and follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats) to see the applicable names of the format to specify in the ingestion command or the EventHub connection.

Comment: Thank you very much! Updating the Data Connection did the trick!